# Mocking the method of a class returned from an exported function

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, mocking, jestjs

I'm wanting to mock a method of a class returned from a module's exports, and I'm having a hard time setting up a Jest test to do so.

Here's what I have:

```
// src/jwks.js

const jwksClient = require('jwks-rsa')
const client = jwksClient({...})
module.exports = client
```

```
// src/auth.js

const jwksClient = require('./jwks')

function getKey (header, callback) {
  jwksClient.getSigningKey(header.kid, function (err, key) {
    console.log("inside getSigningKey")
    var signingKey = key.publicKey || key.rsaPublicKey
    callback(err, signingKey)
  })
}

exports.getKey = getKey
```

```
// src/auth.test.js

const jwksClient = require('./jwks')
const { getKey } = require('./auth')

const mockGetSigningKey = jest.fn(() => {
    console.log("mockGetSigningKey called")
    return {
        publickey: "the-key"
    }
})

jest.mock('./jwks', () => {
  return jest.fn().mockImplementation(() => {
    return {
        getSigningKey: mockGetSigningKey
    }
  })
})

test('test mocked behavior', () => {
    getKey("somekey", (err, key) => {
        console.log("received key: " + key)
    })
}
```

I get the following error:
TypeError: jwksClient.getSigningKey is not a function

```
  2 | 
  3 | function getKey (header, callback) {
> 4 |   jwksClient.getSigningKey(header.kid, function (err, key) {
    |              ^
  5 |     console.log("inside getSigningKey")
  6 |     var signingKey = key.publicKey || key.rsaPublicKey
  7 |     callback(err, signingKey)
```

How do I go about doing this properly? I've tried a lot of different variations and none of them are working for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You didn't mock `./jwks` module correctly. Here is the solution:

`auth.js`:

```js
const jwksClient = require('./jwks');

function getKey(header, callback) {
  jwksClient.getSigningKey(header.kid, function (err, key) {
    console.log('inside getSigningKey');
    var signingKey = key.publicKey || key.rsaPublicKey;
    callback(err, signingKey);
  });
}

exports.getKey = getKey;
```

`jwks.js`:

```
// whatever
```

`auth.test.js`:

```js
const { getKey } = require('./auth');
const jwksClient = require('./jwks');

jest.mock('./jwks', () => {
  return { getSigningKey: jest.fn() };
});

describe('62544352', () => {
  it('should pass', () => {
    jwksClient.getSigningKey.mockImplementationOnce((key, callback) => {
      const key = { publicKey: 'publicKey' };
      callback(null, key);
    });
    const mCallback = jest.fn();
    getKey({ kid: 'someKey' }, mCallback);
    expect(jwksClient.getSigningKey).toBeCalledWith('someKey', expect.any(Function));
    expect(mCallback).toBeCalledWith(null, 'publicKey');
  });
});
```

unit test result with coverage report:

```sh
 PASS  stackoverflow/62544352/auth.test.js (10.232s)
  62544352
    ✓ should pass (28ms)

  console.log
    inside getSigningKey

      at stackoverflow/62544352/auth.js:5:13

----------|---------|----------|---------|---------|-------------------
File      | % Stmts | % Branch | % Funcs | % Lines | Uncovered Line #s 
----------|---------|----------|---------|---------|-------------------
All files |     100 |       50 |     100 |     100 |                   
 auth.js  |     100 |       50 |     100 |     100 | 6                 
----------|---------|----------|---------|---------|-------------------
Test Suites: 1 passed, 1 total
Tests:       1 passed, 1 total
Snapshots:   0 total
Time:        11.65s
```

Comment: Ah, good catch! Worked like a charm. Thank you very much.